# In Dart, how to ensure stream updates are finished before moving on?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, stream, flutter

I am programming in Dart 2.1.0, trying to update some states by listening to a custom stream:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  final controller = StreamController<int>();
  final divisibleBy2 = controller.stream.map((i) => i % 2 == 0);

  var seen2x = false;
  divisibleBy2.listen((y) {
    seen2x = y;
  });

  controller.add(2);
  print(seen2x);
}
```

When I run it, it prints `false`. Apparently, the `print` function is called sooner than the listener function. The state is not updated in time.

By `await`-ing on `controller.add(2)`, I can get the order straight:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  final controller = StreamController<int>();
  final divisibleBy2 = controller.stream.map((i) => i % 2 == 0);

  var seen2x = false;
  divisibleBy2.listen((y) {
    seen2x = y;
  });

  await controller.add(2);
  print(seen2x);
}
```

Now it prints `true`. The listener function is called before `print`.

But **why does `await` make a difference in this case?** [StreamController's add() method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/StreamController/add.html) does *not* return a Future, so I am not sure why `await` matters. In fact, in my real-world usage where the stream network gets more complicated, `await` sometimes is not enough to ensure the order of execution. That's a question for another day.

For now, I just want to see if `await` is the proper way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `sync` parameter in `StreamController` constructor

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I did try it, and am reluctant to use it. According to the [docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/SynchronousStreamController-class.html), there are a lot of caveats to using a synchronous StreamController because it "can be used to break the contract on Stream". In my test, it does cause some weird, unexpected behaviors.

Comment: In the end, I realize that mutating states like I did above alongside streams is really not the right way to approach the problem. I modify the stream network to spew out the new state at the end, instead of mutating state in the middle. Now everything works fine.

Comment: good, your initial "ordering" requirements sounded weird at first ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the `await` made a difference here is that *any* `await` will wait at least a microtask - regardless of whether the value you are awaiting is a `Future` or not. If it is a `Future` it will wait for it to complete or a microtask if it is already complete. It would behave identically if you had `await null;` following the `controller.add(2);`.

In general a `StreamController` doesn't know when all listeners have received the event, especially considering things like async listeners or [`Stream.asyncMap`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html).

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to add an alternate answer for what I did when waiting for a stream to complete. `await for` was the key that I was looking for.

```
var myStream = CustomCacheManager().getFile(_url);
File fetchedFile;
await for (var fileInfo in myStream) {
  fetchedFile = fileInfo.file;
}

// stream is finished now
```